# How do I add child views to a ContainerView

Tags: ember.js

I am following EmberJS online documentation and am uncertain about how to add child view(s) to a parent or nested child view(s) to a parent. I downloaded Ember start-up folder and working with the files. I am able to view the "MainView". It all makes sense so far but when I try to follow the online documentation with regards to views and children views, I am not able to get the child view going.

My current code:

```
window.App = Em.Application.create();

App.MainView = Em.View.extend({
classNames: ['mainView']
});
```

This is the index file code:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
{{#view App.MainView}}
  <h1>Hello world!</h1>
{{/view}}
</script>
```

Code listed below is what causing me confusion.

I tried plugging in the following code to see if anything would pop on to the screen, but I am sure I am approaching it wrong. Any help on this would highly be appreciated.

```
var container = Ember.ContainerView.create();
container.append();

var coolView = App.CoolView.create(),
childViews = container.get('childViews');

childViews.pushObject(coolView);
```

- How can I push lets say "containerView" which now has "coolView" as a child to my "MainView"?
- How will I need to nest the views within index file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've created a jsfiddle which demonstrates the answers to your questions here: http://jsfiddle.net/6ksqd/1/

This is a very contrived example, but hopefully it will help you get the hang of it.

Comment: Luke, I cannot thank you enuff for your help. Yes, your script works, but I would highly appreciate it if you can help me out with Ember's online code example  |||                                     var container =    Ember.ContainerView.create();
container.append();

var coolView = App.CoolView.create(),
    childViews = container.get('childViews');

childViews.pushObject(coolView);

Comment: Happy to look into it. Can you point me to where you found that sample code?

Comment: Hello Luke, Appreciate it. It's under this title of the online documentation "Manually Managed Views with Ember.ContainerView". Here is the link: http://emberjs.com#views

Comment: @Combustion007 here is a working fiddle with the ContainerView example you asked about: http://jsfiddle.net/UW5DE/1/

Comment: thanks a zillion. I had spent couple of days trying to get this going. I appreciate all your help. And thanks for introducing me to JSFiddle as well, it is fantastic.

Comment: I have similar issue please see question details in gist
Here are the details about my question - https://gist.github.com/shivanibhanwal/46603ad0c7d8bfa16609
This is the jsbin - http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gatoja/8/